# Firebase Cloud Functions access Firebase Hosting files

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, angular-universal

I am trying to create a SEO friendly Angular (4) application. This application is built using Firebase (+ AngularFire2). But the current problem I am having is that I can not access the ngfactory that is necessary for an Angular Universal app (I believe).

So my question was, is it possible for Firebase Cloud Functions to access the Firebase Hosting files. I believe that would allow me to access that ngfactory file I need to generate the html for my SEO.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Functions can access any file available via an HTTP request.  So, if your ngfactory file has a URL, you can certainly download it and use it within a function.

You can also deploy any file along with your functions by simply placing it in your functions directory.  And you can then read that file locally during a function's invocation.

Comment: the problem is, I cannot find do something like `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'));`

Comment: @Doug Stevenson I have been struggling to read template files I saved in /templates under the functions directory so that I can use it with nunjucks template engine and send emails. It is not working.

Comment: @Po10cio Please ask this as a new question showing exactly what you are doing that doesn't work the way you expect.